# How to get ApplicationSettings in a class library for winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, configurationmanager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="MyApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  
  <applicationSettings>
    <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ShortDateFormat" serializeAs="String">
        <value>dd/MM/yyyy</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ShortDateFormatWithPeriod" serializeAs="String">
        <value>dd.MM.yyyy</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="TimeFormat24Hour" serializeAs="String">
        <value>HH:mm</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="TimeFormat24HourWithSecond" serializeAs="String">
        <value>HH:mm:ss</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="TimeSpanFormat" serializeAs="String">
        <value>hh\:mm</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="TimeSpanFormatWithSecond" serializeAs="String">
        <value>hh\:mm\:ss</value>
      </setting>
    </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have this `app.config` file. I would like to get value of `ShortDateFormat` from it in a class library. I understand `ConfigurationManager` is the way to do it. But after many failed attempts I have begun to wonder if it's even possible.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
var conf = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("applicationSettings");
```

=> returns null

```
var conf = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyApp.Properties.Settings");
```

=> returns null

The following block of code gives me the section. But I don't see anything in the section that would give me the value of the property.

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var sectionGroup = config.GetSectionGroup("applicationSettings");
var section = sectionGroup.Sections["MyApp.Properties.Settings"];
```

So am I missing anything? Is there a way to get the value for "ShortDateFormat" and other properties?

Comment: The application will read the configuration file for the currently running executable. It will ignore the .config file that is in the class library. So you just need to place this configuration in your executable's .config file, and then you should be able to access it from your class library code via the ConfigurationManager class.

Comment: @mason: that's what I tried to do. But the as I mentioned in the code GetSection returns null.

Comment: Have you considered using `appSettings` style configuration instead of `applicationSettings`? Then you don't have to mess around with section groups and sections and you can just use `AppSetting["PropertyName"]`

Comment: @mason: I can't it's the settings file for WinForm. and WinForm writes its app.config in this fashion.

Comment: You can use app settings. Just open up the config file.

Answer (score -1):

you can get like AppSetting["PropertyName"].ToString();

else
you can create property file under Resources and set all the Property and create one Model with Property where you can use get;set; for each Property.

Comment: The `AppSetting` class is not for obtaining settings from a custom `applicationSettings` section.